# C# for and parallel for loops with batches logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I have a for loop written that handles adding items to a list in batches of 20 like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < filteredList.Count; i = i + 20)
  {
    newlist.Add(GetResponse(filteredList.Skip(i).Take(20)));
  }
```

And this works absolutely fine with smaller lists. So now I was thinking to speed things up when I'm working with larger lists with 10-15000 items inside them to use parallel for loop?

I tried something like this:

```
Parallel.For(0,filteredList.Count, i=>{
i+=20;
newlist.Add(GetResponse(filteredList.Skip(i).Take(20)));
});
```

But this doesn't gives me the wanting results... Is there any way to do perform batch insert other than regular for loop, in a faster manner where execution time would improve over plain for loop ?

Comment: You can't do this... for a start I presume newList is not thread safe? What collection type is it? Also you would have to materialize your query before sending it to the thread... so do .Skip().Take().ToList() then pass THAT LIST through your loop

Comment: @Milney correct  newList is not thread safe, I completely forgot about that... What if I used concurrent bag instead of list?

Comment: @User987 why use *anything*. You can rewrite this as PLINQ and collect the results into a List. You could add the filtering operation that generates `filteredList` in the PLINQ query and speed up the entire operation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you show me an example ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>` **is not** *thread safe*, that's why

```
  Parallel.For(... {
    ...
    newlist.Add(GetResponse(filteredList.Skip(i).Take(20)));
    ...
  });
```

is a wrong technique. Try using *Parallel Linq* (Plinq) instead:

```
newList.AddRange(filteredList
  .AsParallel()
  .Select((value, index) => new {
     value = value,
     index = index })
  .GroupBy(item => item.index / 20)
  .Select(chunk => GetResponse(chunk.Select(item => item.value))));
```

Comment: You don't need `ToList()` if you are going to pass the result to `AddRange`. On the other hand, if `newList` contains the results of the parallel operation, you can just assign the result of `ToList()` to it

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: thank you! You're quite right: premature materialization - `.ToList()` - is evil

Comment: @DmitryBychenko for some reason it gives me error on these two lines of code:  value = value,index = index saying "expected ;" ?

Comment: @User987: I'm sorry for typo: `(value, index) => new {value = value, index = index}`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko if you don't mind could you please explain the code a bit, sorry for I haven't used AsParallel anytime

Comment: @DmitryBychenko in groupby statement it says now: "Operator / cannot be applied to operands of type "method group" and "int"" xD

Comment: @User987: need more coffee: ;( -  `item.index / 20` - `index` should be in lower case

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you're the man! =D Um now it says "chunk does not contains definitio for value " xD

Comment: @DmitryBychenko okay i see u edited answer ill try this one

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It says now: Cannot convert from DB_Layer.SearchedUserItems to System.Collection.Generic.Collections.IEnumerable<SearchedUserItems>" xD ... I pass a IEnumerable to the method itself (ie the take(20) method)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko not that it works just flawless, it's like Boeing 747 fast :D

Comment: @User987: I have to personally apologize for *N + 1 edits*

Comment: when working with parallel it's best to use ConcurrentBag instead of List